# How to set a UIButton as both Selected and Disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrol, uicontrolstate

Attempting to toggle both the selected and enabled attribute on a UIButton, therefore creating 4 potential states (Selected & Disabled, Selected & Enabled, Unselected & Disabled, unselected & Enabled).

In viewDidLoad I define the the images for the button states

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BLUE_IMAGE] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:GREY_IMAGE] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

In viewWillAppear I conditionally set the enabled attribute along with a property (we'll call self.buttonShouldBeSelected) which then sets the UIButton's selected attribute in its setter. Along with some debugging code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // default control states
    self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

    if (self.aBoolean) {
         self.buttonShouldBeSelected = [self.aNSNumber boolValue];
    }
}

- (void)setButtonShouldBeSelected:(BOOL)buttonShouldBeSelected
{
    self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.selected = buttonShouldBeSelected;
    _buttonShouldBeSelected = buttonShouldBeSelected;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    NSLog(@"SELECTED: %u", self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.selected);
    NSLog(@"ENABLED: %u", self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.enabled);
    NSLog(@"STATE: %lu", self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.state);
}
```

This works in all cases aside from one, when the button is disabled and in the selected state. In this case the UI displays the BLUE_IMAGE instead of the selected state's GREY_IMAGE and the button is correctly disabled.

In this case the log results in...

```
SELECTED: 1
ENABLED: 0
STATE: 6
```

What am I doing wrong, why is it showing the image for NormalState and what does UIControlState == 6 mean?

Comment: Try replacing UIControlStateSelected with (UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected)

Comment: adding UIControlStateHighlighted had no change

Comment: Thanks Josh...while your solution wasn't exactly right, it got me thinking on the right path. I added a 3rd setImage: forState:, setting GREY_IMAGE for (UIControlStateDisabled | UIControlStateSelected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to add third state declaration

```
[self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:GREY_IMAGE] forState:(UIControlStateDisabled | UIControlStateSelected)]
```

Answer (score 4):

And for Swift 3:

```
inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.setImage(UIImage(named: GREY_IMAGE), for: [.disabled, .selected])
```

Answer (score 4):

I have come in to the same problem. I used property **isUserInteractionEnabled** instead of **isEnabled**, so the button can remain status where it was before.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift:

```
inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.setImage(UIImage(named: GREY_IMAGE), forState: [.Disabled, .Selected])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting tint color to nil?

```
[self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how combining states worked for me in Swift:

```
let state = UIControl.State.selected.union(UIControl.State.disabled)
button.setImage(image, for: state)
```